# How to change item in a spinner in ActionBar programmatically

Tags: android, spinner

I have a spinner in my ActionBarSherlock with 5 elements in it. By clicking one of the two buttons at the bottom of the screen (see picture) I want to change the `item id` of the `spinner`.

[image]

This is the relevant code:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
/* ... some code ...*/
Context context = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.arr_contents, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item);
list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);
    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(list, this);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
/*... some other code ...*/
}


@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {

    switch(itemPosition) {
        case 0:
            // Do stuff
            break;
        case 1:
            // Do stuff
            break;
        case 2:
            // Do stuff
            break;
        case 3:
            // Do stuff
            break;
        case 4:
            // Do stuff
            break;
        default:
            // Do stuff
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I've tried calling `onNavigationItemSelected(3, R.array.arr_contents);` for example to move to the third element of the spinner but it doesn't work.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure but probably:

```
getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(itemPosition);
```

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setSelectedNavigationItem%28int%29)